# What's the best way to deploy a npmjs Private Module?

Tags: npm

npmjs recently released their [private npm modules feature](https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules) which looks pretty cool.

To publish or fetch a private module from npm you need to have an authenticated npm client using `npm login` so the `.npmrc` file will get updated or created with the access token.

What is the best practice to deploy or CI an application that uses a private module?

Comment: Up to now the best way I could find is to include the `.npmrc` file in my repo with the login credentials `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=xxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to include the .npmrc file but replace the auth token with an environment variable. [Step 4 of this tutorial](http://blog.getpiggybank.com/npm-private-modules-with-heroku/) shows you how to do this and should work for any CI/deployment scenario.

If you are using Heroku, then you can follow Step 5 to set the environment variable. If not, just figure out how you configure env variables for the service you're using.

Comment: It might be best to copy the instruction here, linked site seems to be unavailable...